# ETA Field Validation

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, date-time, validation

I have a list which has an ETA data/time control. I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent users from entering a date which is before the current date/time?

Answer (score 3):

Batman,

This should help:
[How to Validate a Due Date in a SharePoint 2010 List](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2011/02/how-to-validate-a-due-date-in-a-sharepoint-2010-list/)

In short use Column Validations in Column Settings, a short formula can be:

> [Due Date] > Today()